# Sort by the number of occurrences of the foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables

```
    CREATE TABLE restaurants (
        id      BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name    VARCHAR(255),
        address VARCHAR(255)
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE votes (
        id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        restaurant_id BIGINT,
        FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants(id)
    );
```

The Restaurant belongs to the Vote of one-to-many. Each restaurant can have multiple votes. Help write a query that returns all restaurants sorted by the number of votes.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do restaurants left join votes and select count of vote and restaurant name, then group by restaurant id, order by the count.

Here is the query I tested and worked:

```
SELECT res.name as restaurant_name, 
COUNT(vo.id) AS count 
FROM restaurants res
LEFT JOIN votes vo 
ON res.id=vo.restaurant_id 
GROUP BY restaurant_name 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Tell me, if I want to receive not only res.name, but all data about restaurants, should I rewrite them manually?

Comment: yes of course you can retrieve all data in this query

Comment: I understood you. Thank you very much again, you helped me a lot, I lost half a day because of this.